# Keep Windows Terminal tab open after invoked WSL command

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, windows-terminal

I'm trying to open a **WSL (Ubuntu) tab** in **Windows Terminal**, and then run a command in that tab using WSL. I use the following PowerShell command for that:

```
wt new-tab -p "WSL (Ubuntu)" wsl echo "hallo"
```

The problem is, after `echo` has run, the tab closes immediately.
Is there a way to keep it open?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- When you pass a command line to `wt.exe`, the Windows Terminal CLI, it is run *instead* of a shell, irrespective of whether you also specify a specific shell profile with `-p`.
- Thus, to achieve what you want:

  - Your command line must *explicitly* invoke the shell of interest...
  - ...*and* that shell must support starting an interactive, stay-open session *in combination with startup commands*.

While PowerShell supports this, POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` - WSL's default shell - do not.

A - suboptimal - *workaround* is the following:

```
wt -p 'WSL (Ubuntu)' wsl -e bash -c 'echo ''hello''\; exec $BASH'
```

Note:

- Inexplicably, as of Windows Terminal v1.13.11431.0,
  the `;` char. inside the quoted `-c` argument requires escaping as `\;` - otherwise it is interpreted by `wt.exe` as *its* separator for opening *multiple* tabs / windows.
- The above executes the specified `echo` command first, and then uses `exec` to replace the non-interactive, auto-closing original shell with an interactive, stay-open session via `exec`. The limitation of this approach is that any state changes other than environment-variable definitions made by the startup command(s) are lost when the original shell is replaced.

  - A better, but more elaborate solution is possible: create a temporary copy of Bash's initialization file, `~/.bashrc`, append your startup commands, and pass the temporary copy's file path to `bash`'s `--rcfile` option; delete the temporary copy afterwards.